# What gets shared?

Tags: google-mirror-api

Something is unclear to me with regards to the share action.

Does the sharing endpoint (google+ contacts, or other subscribed glassware) receive the timeline item with whatever it contains (html, attachment...)?

Example:

If I have this item in my timeline...

```
  {
   "menuItems": [{"action": "SHARE"}],
   "html": "<div>a beautiful HTML card</div>",
   "location": {
    "latitude": 40.702587,
    "timestamp": "2013-05-20T19:22:56.164600",
    "displayName": "KLOMPCHING GALLERY",
    "longitude": -73.98926,
    "address": "111 Front Street"
   },
   "id": 42004,
   "isDeleted": false,
   "kind": "mirror#timelineItem"
  }
```

...and I click on share: the sharing endpoint would receive this same JSON object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By inserting a timeline card with the `SHARE` menuItem, you let the user share this card with other Glassware that supports this type of card (e.g image, video, link, etc.).

When a user decides to share this card with another Glassware, this is what happens:

1. Glass creates a copy of the timeline card (including attachments, html, text, recipients, etc.).
2. Glass sets the ownership of the copy to the Glassware it is shared with.
3. If the Glassware is subscribed to notifications, the Mirror API sends a notification to the Glassware: it is now up to the Glassware to process the `SHARE` action.

You can checkout this Google I/O session about [Building Glass Services with the Mirror API](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CxB1DuwGRqk) that we did last week to learn more about the sharing model.

Comment: Can you define "Glassware that supports this type of card"? A glassware can subscribe to share (https://developers.google.com/glass/subscriptions#shared_picture) but where is the type of card specified?

Comment: This is specified by the Glassware's [`contact.acceptTypes`](https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/contacts#acceptTypes). According to the properties the the timeline card has, its type can be set to `image/*` (image attachment), `video/*` (video attachment), `text/plain` (text property set) or `text/html` (html property set).